# Contar cuantos registros hay en la query de un modelo - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Buenos días estoy intentando contar cuantos registros hay en una relación, pero no consigo acertar en como hacerlo.

**Con esta consulta en mi modelo saco las fotos que tiene este id**

```
public function galeria()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(Galeria::class, 'idVivienda');
        
  }
```

**Pero luego intento hacer un...**

```
public function galeria()
  {
        return $this->hasMany(Galeria::class, 'idVivienda')->count();
            
  }
```

Entonces no se muy bien como puedo hacerlo ¿Es posible?

Enseño la query del controlado por si fuera necesario:

```
$propiedad = Vivienda::with('etiqueta')
                            ->with('poblacion')
                            ->with('elDistrito')
                            ->with('galeria')
                            ->where('slug', $slug)->first();
```

Comment: ¿Y por qué no usar `->withCount('galeria')`?

Comment: No sabia que existia eso @JonatanLavado y funciona perfecto! SI quieres ponerlo como respuesta!